# Deployment of java web application on internet

Tags: java

I have developed an web application in java using Apache tomcat server and MS sql database,its working fine in offline,i want to deploy it online,Apart from purchasing domain name,how to deploy it online,i dont have any public ip machine,i need third party,will third parties provide remote acess to tomcat and sql,if so how to configure mine there,consider it as small application,since its my first deployment please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try [openshift](https://openshift.redhat.com/)

It has no MSSql but it has PostgreSQL and MySQL

Comment: so are you suggesting me to go for cloud?

Comment: Why not? The alternatives are hosting it by yourself or on a root server...